# Trying to wrap my head around Custom Identity tables with a DB first approach

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

My entire group is new to ASP.Net Core and I was the lucky one tasked with Authentication/Authorization.  We have always used a DB first approach, and this is no different, we already have our DB all set up.  The higher ups want to use our specific tables for all things Identity, but they also want to leverage the tools that ASP.Net Core gives.

This will be a multi-site app where there is one central database.  Our current setup is close to what the scaffolding adds, but has some small differences.

I have read a ton of resources, but the vast majority all focus on the code first approach and I currently don't fully understand what I need and what is there for the code first approach. I have seen a couple of answers that recommend using the .ToTable and .Property inside of OnModelCreate.  Is this the best option or am I better off creating my own stores and methods?  I currently have a user model created and a store to go with it (based on [this site](http://danderson.io/posts/using-your-own-database-schema-and-classes-with-asp-net-core-identity-and-entity-framework-core/)).  Is it best for me to try to expand that all the way out (don't full understand how to have it pull in roles and claims).

This is what our DB Schema currently looks like.
[image]

At this point we are creating our Roles and Claims via a db script. The only thing we will be using UI's for right now is a page that will let a site admin add users, and assign them roles, and any singular claims they need.

Any help or input would be greatly appreciated as I try to wrap my head around all of this.  If I have left out any pertinent information please let me know. As I said with what I have now I can create a user and login, I just have no idea where to go from here (how to add roles and claims).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I think about it and the steps I would take to approach in solving this problem.

So Microsoft's implementation of Identity is an abstraction of the problem.

The Models that they provide and the Tables that are derived from them is their choice for the default implementation of the abstraction.

So essentially what you want to do is to plug in your models in to this abstraction.

To quickly generate these models from your database you might want to use [scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db#reverse-engineer-your-model) this will generate the DbContext and the Models, you will then have to configure the dbcontext to plug in your design.

And if you look at how you can create your own Identity Tables providing your own objects
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2) this can give you an idea of how to plug in your models/functions in to this abstraction.

You will most likely have to override the `OnModelCreating` method to configure the relationship of your tables.